# cockroachDb : Only Truncate if table exists

Tags: sql, cockroachdb

How can one truncate a table only if the table exists in cockroachdb?
I want to delete all the records in a table in cockroachdb.
This table may or maynot be present.
How can I truncate the table only if it exists in cockroachdb.

I can see that IF exists is used in mysql.But I am unable to find similar syntax in cockroach db.

```
truncate table IF exists table1;
```

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "exists"
DETAIL:  source SQL:
truncate table IF exists table1;
```

Comment: Is appears not to be supported (but there is a request for it already) https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/37798 so it must probably be done by having a separate script checking for existence and returning 0/1. This return then determines if the truncate script is called or not.

Comment: Your syntax is not correct. See here https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/truncate.html. The alternate way is to DROP TABLE IF EXISTS then create it again.

Comment: You could also perhaps truncate the table and just ignore the error when it does not exist (if you dont want to drop it)..

Comment: Thank you @SAS and ankit Bajpal for your valuable input.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from SAS above is correct. [GitHub issue #37798](http://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/37798) discusses this syntax, and based on [this comment](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/37798#issuecomment-519148961), it seems unlikely that we'll support this syntax any time soon (if ever), since it's not supported by Postgres. [That comment](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/37798#issuecomment-519148961) also mentions two workarounds (one of which was also mentioned by Ankit Bajpai above): either `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` followed by `CREATE TABLE`, or `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` followed by `TRUNCATE`.